# Php get mutliple values from a single column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a mySql Table with many columns :

[image: Table Structure]

I have one column "Tete" with an array list.

I want to make a query to get all the values in this field, somethink like this :

- foo
- bar
- hello
- world

I use a PDO connexion :

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=perfume', 'perfume', '', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

And then to get all my informations :

```
<?php $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM parfums WHERE id='{$id}'"); 
 while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){
<p>"<?php echo $donnees['Description']; ?>
}
```

But I don't know how to dissociate the value from "Tete" Colum, I tried something like this :

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM parfums WHERE  id='{$id}'");
while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($reponse))
{
   $array= unserialize($rs['Coeur']);
    print_r($array);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: what datatype is the `tete` column exactly? I assume a string type. If so, you'll need to use some PHP code to get the values apart. You can use the PHP function [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) to split them all into an array of values.

Comment: `unserialize` will only work if you `serialize` the data going in. PHP uses it's own format for serializing/unserializing. You appear to have the data in a csv format and could then use [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse it to an array. Also, storing multiple values in a single column is a horrible way to store the data. You should be using a separate table that you join together. You will have a hard time querying that column for a single value and even if you can query it, it will be pretty bad performance-wise

Comment: On a sidenote, if you're using PDO, then why do I see a call to `mysql_fetch_assoc` in your code??? You can't mix the two.

Comment: Normalize your database